# Linking IBM Watson assistant to a regression model in Python?

Tags: python, ibm-watson

I want the IBM Watson assistant to react to same intents differently depending on the outcome of a scoring. Where should I start?

Comment: Is the scoring available as an API? If so you could write a Webhook which would in turn invoke the scoring API.

Comment: Thank you, I will check this.